# Restrict network access for a single process with SELinux or AppArmor

Tags: network, access-control, selinux, apparmor

I have a Python script that access the network, and I want to deny it network access sometimes. How can I achieve this with SELinux or AppArmor? I want to be able to launch this specific script with restricted access.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network policies under AppArmor/SELinux](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5969/network-policies-under-apparmor-selinux)

Answer (score 2):

AppArmor has the ability to block network connections from applications. I've never done it myself, but you should look at the [AppArmor community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) and the [network rules](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/ProfileLanguage#Network_rules) page for details on how to do it.

From the looks of it, the `deny network` directive should allow you to block all network access for an application.

Comment: thanks a lot, but suddenly I could not run apparmor - `AppArmor not available as kernel LSM` famous bug:(

Answer (score 1):

If you have SELinux enabled, I was under the impression that the default action was to deny access so what you want to do is to allow network access at times, right?

I suspect that you going to have to do something like this [answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/366922/selinux-limit-httpd-outbound-connections-by-address-and-port), which contains SE Linux configuration for a single process `httpd` and then combines that configuration with `iptables` to control the network access.

To add in the `time` aspect, there's a [`time` module](https://serverfault.com/questions/366922/selinux-limit-httpd-outbound-connections-by-address-and-port) in iptables. Here's a [link](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/iptables-time-modul-935075/) showing some real usage on another forum.

AppArmor has already been well-answered :)

Answer (score 1):

AppArmor profile for this case is:

```
profile nonetwork /path/to/exec {
  # Allow all rules...
  capability,
  network,
  mount,
  remount,
  umount,
  pivot_root,
  ptrace,
  signal,
  dbus,
  unix,
  file,
  # ...but no network
  deny network,
  deny capability net_admin,
  deny capability net_bind_service,
  deny capability net_broadcast,
  deny capability net_raw,
}
```

Nowadays not all linux distros support some features, for example Debian 10 not support `network`, `unix`, `dbus` rules. So this profile will not works in such distros.